# What is the purpose of "tower loss" in TensorFlow multi-GPU code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, multi-gpu

I am trying to write multi-GPU TensorFlow code for my project and came across the [CIFAR10 code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py) in the TensorFlow repo. I don't quite understand the use of `tower_loss` in the code. Why can't we just use `loss = cifar10.loss(logits, labels)` in place of line 178 and take the average of all losses?

Comment: The link is dead!